# Unable to get value of JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

I have an object called DataObj with property names like the following

```
DataObj.Question1
DataObj.Question2
DataObj.Question3 and so on
```

Each of the question property, it has an array size of 3, which holds a Yes/No/NA flag for their respective questions
Example

```
Q1. Do you smoke?
Yes [x]
No  [ ]
N/A [ ]

DataObj.Question1[0] = true
DataObj.Question1[1] = false
DataObj.Question1[2] = false
```

I'm trying to write a loop that goes through each question, see which one is checked, and fill out a word template and I am using the working code below as my guide.

```
if (DataObj.Question1[0] == true) 
{
    WScript.Echo("Yes");
    template.setValue("Q1Y", true);
}
```

Question: When I create a loop with a variable i as my number counter, and append it to DataObj.Question, how can I add the [0] to the end of DataObj.Question + i to be able to access the data? I am sure that trying to build the object with the [n] is giving me issues and I don't know if what I am doing is ever possible.

```
for (i = 1; i<16; i++) 
{     
        if (DataObj.Question + i + [0] === true) 
        {
            template.setValue("Q" + i + "Y", true);
        }   
        else if (DataObj.Question + i + [1] === true) 
        {
            template.setValue("Q" + i + "N", true);
        }
        else if (DataObj.Question + i + [2] === true)
        {
            template.setValue("Q" + i + "NA", true);
        } 
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you think `DataObj.Question + i + [0]` is doing. If you want to access `QuestionN` from `DataObj` you'd need `DataObj['Question' + i][0]` But still ew; why not keep it in an array/hash anyway?

Comment: @DaveNewton I provided that snipit showing that I at least tried the problem, even though I knew that was wrong. The 'DataObj['Question' + i][0]' is what I am looking for, thanks! The code is from a friend who I'm working with on a side project.

Comment: Here's the answer in a fiddle anyway:

https://jsfiddle.net/1accpcb4/